# Can't upload an image to the server in Godaddy server while its working fine on the local server (xampp)

Tags: php, html, mysql, godaddy-api

Why I can't upload an image to the server in Godaddy server while its working fine on the local server (xampp). Here is my code:

```php
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
`include('includes/config.php');`
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
  { 
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
$testimonoial=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$email=$_SESSION['login'];
$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"domuents/img/".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$sql="INSERT INTO  tbltestimonial(UserEmail,imagename,mytmp) VALUES(:email,:testimonoial,:imagetmp)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':testimonoial',$testimonoial,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':imagetmp',$imagetmp,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
if($lastInsertId)
{
$msg="تم تحميل الوثسقة بنجاح";
}
else 
{
$error="حدث خطا ما . الرجاء اعادة المحاولة";
}

}
?>
```

here is my form code

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="uppercase underline">تحميل وثائق</h5>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="btn" required>
      <span class="angle_arrow">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn" style="margin:28px">
   </div>
</form>
```

I use godaddy host and domain with phpmyadmin database.
I searched a lot but nothing and also i tried to delete the move to folder text and nothing.
I've checked if the tables are still with the same text as the local server and all fine.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you have some error print by your application ? Maybe size problem of the file was send. Or the destination path are not exists or are not writable.

Comment: Check if any of the folders have capital letters, i have had an issue like this the folder was Documents but i had documents in the code

Comment: @TaariqSolomons yes its all fine all the folders are the same as the in the code.

Comment: @Inazo its all good .

Comment: Also check for permissions errors

Answer (score 0):

Does the folder `domuents/img/` exist on your godaddy hosting? Especially notice that you have a typo there `domuents` while I guess you wanted to have `documents`.

Comment: yes its exists and its like with the same as i typed

Comment: if you execute in your code `var_dump($_FILES); die('stopped');`, for example before line `$testimonoial=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];` do you get any contents or an empty array?

Comment: array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(36) "28fa4e453cc452fa284db32d716f33f9.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpzxkYsu" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(69733) } } thats the error

Comment: that is not an error, that is a dump of the $_FILES array and it shows us that we actually have the file. So now replace the added line with `var_dump(file_exists("domuents/img/")); var_dump(is_dir("domuents/img/")); var_dump(is_writable("domuents/img/"));` You should get "true true true" as result, if something is different then it means that folder does not exist or is not writable.